# Xamarin.Android how to override style from nuget library?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-styles

I'm using for example [BottomNavigationBarXF](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF) library in my Xamarin.Android project and I would like to change font which it uses. I found in source code styles responsible for that, but I don't know how to override them without adding library source code to my project.

Style are here: [source code](https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar/blob/master/src/bottom-navigation-bar/Resources/values/styles.xml).

Is it possible? I would like to change font for this one: `BB_BottomBarItem_Fixed.TitleAppearance`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible? I would like to change font for this one:BB_BottomBarItem_Fixed.TitleAppearance

According to [README of BottomNavigationBar](https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar). You can set the Text Appearance of Bottom `Navigationbar` using `BottomBar.SetTextAppearance(resId)`.

So first step, define a style for text appearance in `styles.xml`:

```
 <style name="MyTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
 </style>
```

Then use this style after you create the bottom bar:

```
var _bottomBar = BottomBar.Attach(this, savedInstanceState);
...
_bottomBar.setTextAppearance(Resource.Style.MyTextAppearance)
```